What chord symbol would you use to describe this voicing?

Actually this is one of exercises in the book that I am reading, and I have encountered this piece.
The chord symbol given is D7.
The chord written is B/D.
How could (D F# B D#) be considered same as (D F# A C)?
I wonder such roughly putting notes together is commonplace in music?

What is the book and who is the author? The written voicings are often incomplete and  the chord symbols often don’t match the written voicings.

the book is Berklee of Jazz Harmony by Mulholland and Hojnacki.

This offers some insight. It would also help if you gave the subject matter of the chapters your music examples contain in order to be able to answer more accurately.

I'd have expected it in a Mark Levine book, but not Berklee! Often there are 'approximations' - which are totally unnecessary, but those notes don't constitute D7.

could also simply be called "D alt". Hard to say D7 as it misses the dom7 but some would argue that presence of b9 and 13 mean that the 7 is "implied". Some of this jazz harmony notation becomes very approximate and open to interpretation at times. Possibly makes perfect sense in the context of the book though.

If it is an exercise from a book, what is the text associated with that music example. If the book is any good, it will tell you the musical point of the example.

The fundamental reason it's confusing is that the printed chord symbols are not an analysis of what lies beneath. I'm guessing the idea is that the double staff is showing what an actual pianist might choose to do here (or did, if it's a transcription?), and they've taken that basic D7 and elaborated it. But its function is still as a D chord (mostly because of the big ol' bass note).

@danmcb alt would suggest b13 (or #5), rather than 13.

@AndyBonner I think your comment could make a good answer to this question.

@user1079505 I've always understood "alt" to mean "dom7 chord altered in an unspecified way", not any specific altered extension such as b13. If it has a more specific meaning than that, I'd like to know, but I'm not aware of such a common understanding. (If the composer specifically wanted b13, why not write it?)

@danmcb "alt" relates to altered scale, which has all possible alterations: b9, #9, #4 and #5 (b13). Of course, not all of them must be played, so if you specifically require b13/#5, you should write it. However, adding a natural 13 makes it a different chord.

It could be written B/D. It could even be written B7/D. Either of those would accurately describe the pitch content.
However, presuming this is an interpretation from a lead sheet, D7 clearly indicates that the chord is part of a ii-V progression (in G major, the apparent key of this [part of the] piece).
The D7 can be "heard" since the chord contains D-F#-A, and the C was just heard in the previous chord, setting the overall tonality. The B then is the 6 or 13 — a chord extension — which also describes the D# (i.e., Eb = b9).
So the symbol to describe the complete voicing would be D7b9(add13) or, since the C isn't literally part of the chord, D6b9.

Based on the fact that this is from a jazz harmony book from Berklee it seems likely this entire example revolves around using triads and 7th chords to form upper structures of basic chords. Triads used in this way are referred to as upper structure triads. These types of chords are called poly chords. They are usually written like a vertical fraction instead of a slash chord. Your example is based on a B triad over a D7 chord, written like this:

This ends up being a D13b9 chord. The B is the 13, the D#(Eb) is b9 and the F# is the 3. In this case the chord symbol indicates that the D7 chord is played under the triad. In this case you can spell the chord from the root but sometimes poly chords don’t have a clear single chord symbol to define them.
There are a few others here, the 1st inversion Ab triad over D7alt gives you 7,b9,#11(b5), C,Eb,Ab. The 2nd inversion F triad over Bbmaj7 gives you the 9,5,7, C,F,A.
